# javascript function before google maps load

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I have to put markes on google maps, but the array with lat, long is made by an Ajax request.
Map is loaded before the initialization of the array and I don't see the markers.
I think that this is the problem but I'm not so sure. hope you can help me

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setVariable('<?php echo $_SESSION["token"]?>');
    });
</script>


<script defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap">
</script>


coord = new Array();

function setVariable(token) {

    format="text/plain";
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + "reports",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: {'x-access-token': token},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if (data.success){
                $.each(data.data.reports, function (i, item) {
                    coord[i] = [ data.data.reports[i].lat , data.data.reports[i].lng ] ;
                });
                console.log(coord)
            }else{
                alert(data.error.message);
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }

    });
}

function initMap() {

    var myLatLng = {lat: 43.1107168, lng: 12.3908279};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(coord[i][0], coord[i][1]),
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }

}
```

How can i resolve this?

thank you very much.

Comment: Have you thought about using promises? It may be what you're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Add markers after AJAX success.

Comment: I have already tried, but id doesn't work. @Hikarunomemory

Comment: Please update the post to show what exactly you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to restructure the code in order to make this work. We need to add markers on the map only after we have fetched the lat/long data successfully by making an AJAX request. We could do this in the following manner.

```
<script defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap">
```

```
/*
We will keep a global variable that would contain a reference to the google map object.

It would be initialized as soon as the script for google maps is loaded and initMap function is called subsequently.

*/

var GoogleMap;

coord = new Array();

function setVariable(token) {

format="text/plain";
$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL + "reports",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: {'x-access-token': token},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        if (data.success){

            $.each(data.data.reports, function (i, item) {
                coord[i] = [ data.data.reports[i].lat , data.data.reports[i].lng ] ;
            });
            console.log(coord)

            var marker, i;
            for (i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(coord[i][0], coord[i][1]),
                map: GoogleMap,
                title: 'Hello World!'
            });
}


        }else{
            alert(data.error.message);
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }

});
}

function initMap() {

var myLatLng = {lat: 43.1107168, lng: 12.3908279};

GoogleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatLng
});

}
```

Hopefully, this should work!